# Change background color when button is active or selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have default  `._sideFolder`  with `background` color of `black`

I want to change the `bgcolor` into `blue` when the `button` is `selected`

```
.zf-folder:active ._sideFolder {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 5px
}
```

The blue color only appears when clicked.

I am really confused with my pseudo CSS. Should I use JavaScript in here?

**[My JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/qb8b4hcj/9/)**

I want to display like in the picture on the left.

**FYI: In my project I use `._sideFolder` with `background-color: red;`**

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table.table').DataTable();
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable().columns.adjust();
  });
});
```

```css
._sideFolder {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 5px
}

.zf-folder:active ._sideFolder {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 5px
}

.zf-folder a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

._tabFolder {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

._tabFolder:hover {
  background-color: grey
}

._tabFolder:active {
  background-color: rgba(29, 33, 41, 1)
}

._itemPosition {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex
}



._iconText:hover ._1i5y,
.uiPopover.selected ._1i5y {
  display: block
}

._iconText {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 13px;
}

._iconFolder,
._1i5x,
._1i5w {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle
}



._5bme ._iconFolder {
  background-image: url(/rsrc.php/v3/yE/r/miCSJRxMvJi.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: -412px -21px
}

.hyperspan {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav">

  <div class="zf-folder">
    <li class="active">
      <div id="tabFolder" class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" style="height: 40px;border-bottom:1px groove; user-select: none;">
        <div class="_sideFolder"></div>
        <div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">
          <div class="ellipsis">
            <div class="_iconFolder">
              <div class="_icon-col">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#mainFolder" aria-controls="mainFolder" data-toggle="tab">Main Folder<span class="hyperspan"></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>

  <div class="zf-folder">
    <li>
      <div id="tabFolder2" class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" style="height: 40px;border-bottom:1px groove; user-select: none;">
        <div class="_sideFolder"></div>
        <div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">
          <div class="ellipsis">
            <div class="_iconFolder">
              <div class="_icon-col">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#secondFolder" aria-controls="secondFolder" data-toggle="tab">Second Folder<span class="hyperspan"></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>

</ul>


<!-- CONTENT -->


<div class="tab-content">

  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="mainFolder">
    <div class="zf-table">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
            <th>Operation</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>
              
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs approve-off" type="submit" value="approve">
                <span class="fa fa-check-square-o"></span> Approve
              </button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs reject-off" type="submit" value="reject">
                <span class="fa fa-times"></span> Reject
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="secondFolder">
    <div class="zf-table">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
            <th>Operation</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>
              <input hidden="hidden" name="offId" />
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-ocoff" type="submit" value="delete">
                <span class="fa fa-times"></span> Delete
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: There are multiple things wrong but to concentrate on your question that you are asking what it sounds like is you dont need psuedo class but you need `.active` classname to the active tab. So just toggle in your current `.active` tab and remove from the other non-active and that should resolve. Also you need to have your CSS as `.zf-folder .active ._sideFolder`

Comment: better im delete class="active" in <li>, right?

Comment: @CalvinAnanda let me know if it works the way you expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I'll try to summarise:

1. The html structure was invalid, unordered lists (`ul`) and ordered
   lists (`ol`) should only contain list items (`li`) as direct
   descendant elements.
2. The `active` class was not toggling off inactive list items
   correctly - this behaviour was rectified by nesting `.zf-folder` inside of
   the list items - which is valid html structuring anyway and was
   addressed in the former point.
3. The styles you have declared for the elements in question for
   `:active` *pseudo-states* should now be declared for `.active` list
   items. You could probably do away with those `:active` styles
   altogether now.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qb8b4hcj/13/)

**Adjusted Selectors:**

```
.zf-folder:active ._sideFolder, li.active .zf-folder ._sideFolder {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 5px
}


._tabFolder:active, li.active ._tabFolder {
  background-color: rgba(29, 33, 41, 1)
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table.table').DataTable();
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable().columns.adjust();
  });
});
```

```css
._sideFolder {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 5px
}

.zf-folder:active ._sideFolder,
li.active .zf-folder ._sideFolder {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 5px
}

.zf-folder a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

._tabFolder {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

._tabFolder:hover {
  background-color: grey
}

._tabFolder:active, li.active ._tabFolder {
  background-color: rgba(29, 33, 41, 1)
}

._itemPosition {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex
}

._iconText:hover ._1i5y,
.uiPopover.selected ._1i5y {
  display: block
}

._iconText {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 13px;
}

._iconFolder,
._1i5x,
._1i5w {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle
}

._5bme ._iconFolder {
  background-image: url(/rsrc.php/v3/yE/r/miCSJRxMvJi.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: -412px -21px
}

.hyperspan {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav">

  <li class="active">
    <div class="zf-folder">
      <div id="tabFolder" class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" style="height: 40px;border-bottom:1px groove; user-select: none;">
        <div class="_sideFolder"></div>
        <div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">
          <div class="ellipsis">
            <div class="_iconFolder">
              <div class="_icon-col">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#mainFolder" aria-controls="mainFolder" data-toggle="tab">Main Folder<span class="hyperspan"></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="zf-folder">
      <div id="tabFolder2" class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" style="height: 40px;border-bottom:1px groove; user-select: none;">
        <div class="_sideFolder"></div>
        <div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">
          <div class="ellipsis">
            <div class="_iconFolder">
              <div class="_icon-col">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#secondFolder" aria-controls="secondFolder" data-toggle="tab">Second Folder<span class="hyperspan"></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>


<!-- CONTENT -->


<div class="tab-content">

  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="mainFolder">
    <div class="zf-table">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
            <th>Operation</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>

              <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs approve-off" type="submit" value="approve">
                <span class="fa fa-check-square-o"></span> Approve
              </button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs reject-off" type="submit" value="reject">
                <span class="fa fa-times"></span> Reject
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="secondFolder">
    <div class="zf-table">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
            <th>Operation</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>
              <input hidden="hidden" name="offId" />
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-ocoff" type="submit" value="delete">
                <span class="fa fa-times"></span> Delete
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, Can you tell me? which code do I need to fix?

Answer (score 1):

May be a bit late. But this is how you can do it.

This approach says to remove the `style` from all of the `divs` and then add it to the `clicked` one

```
$('._tabFolder').click(function(){
 $("._tabFolder").css("cssText", "height: 40px; border-bottom: 1px groove; user-select: none; border-left: solid 0px;");

   $(this).css("cssText", "height: 40px; border-bottom: 1px groove; user-select: none; border-left: solid 5px;");
})
```

Check here the [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dollarsview/qb8b4hcj/17/)

Hope this helps

Comment: That's incredible! Very simple. Just need to change the border size?

Comment: yup. Glad to know it helps :)

Comment: you can accept the answer if it resolved your issue :D

Comment: wait, can you tell me a little to adjust the color of the div too? because it only uses border.

Comment: color of the border ? well if yes. you can add any color to it. For example `border-left: solid 5px green;` Green in this case

Comment: background div. I'm trying to combine the code of all the answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159237/discussion-between-usman-rana-and-calvin-ananda).